# Reload treeview and open in one place - Dynatree

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, dynatree

I'm trying to recharge my treeview using dynatree and expand in the same place where I left off, but I can not.
I'm carrying it whole, making a query in mvc using oracle and returning a shortlist dynatree with the keys already defined.

My code:

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
   selectMode: 3,
   clickFolderMode: 3,
   initAjax: {
   type: "POST",
   url: "/controller/GetTree"
 }
});
```

To recharge the record insert via ajax mvc, the only way to upgrade is to give reload the treeview, so:

```
$("#tree").dynatree("getTree").reload();
```

then try to expand or getnodebykey use, but still does not work

```
$("#tree").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function (node) {
 node.expand(true); 
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Friends, reading of dynatree help, I found the property "persist". Using it got what I wanted.

Persist: true.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cookie persistence functionality or you can do it with something like `tree.selectKey(val).Expand();`  where val is the key of what you need to expand.

You can also use the `generateIds:true;` option when creating the tree so you can access directly the nodes if know the id and can use jquery selector.